# navbar heading doesnt stay in place

Tags: html, css

I want to put a title (a larger font than other text in navbar) on the left hand side of my navbar, so far i have achieved getting it on the left side but the text is being half cut, like half the text is outside the navbar and half of it is inside it. How can i get the text to stay fully inside the navbar?

CSS

```
<style>

 #navbar ul { 
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    background:#1c1c1c;
    }

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 0.5px solid #242424;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding:.3em 1em; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color:transparent; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #ffffff;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#1c1c1c;  
    } 

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:0;
}
 #navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar h1 {
    float: left;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <title>ClickonDeal.com.au-Electronics</title>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        </head>

 <div id="navbar">
        <h1>Click</h1>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">more stuff</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li> 
    </form>
      </ul> 
    </div>  
    </div>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errant closing tags that are throwing errors, but that's not what's causing you trouble.

Likely issue is that H1 in most browsers will have default margins that are pushing it out of whack.

I'd investigate adding a css reset (start at http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) but in the mean time, you can fix this by setting margins to 0 on your h1:

```
#navbar h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here's a simple jsfiddle showing that change: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/BjCBf/1/ (h1 color changed to white so we can see it)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS to your code:

```
#navbar h1 {
    float: left;
    margin:0;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcDrx/)

Comment: @RohanPatel Usually happen :)  Always reset your html, because each browser has it own setting.